# How to implement a method only if it doesn't yet exist

Tags: ruby

I was writing a script in Ruby and realized I needed to use the `Enumerable#sum` method. However, that method only exists in Ruby 2.4 and higher - and I have 2.2.

So I could add the method myself, like this

```
module Enumerable
  def sum(init = 0, &block)
    block ||= lambda { |x| x }
    map(&block).inject(init, :+)
  end
end
```

But if I run the script on a pc where there is high enough version of Ruby, my implementation will override the one from standard library.

How do I implement the `Enumerable#sum` method if and only if it doesn't exist?

Comment: You should take a look at Marc-André Lafortune's [backports](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem! Just require the method you're interested in, e.g. `require 'backports/2.4.0/enumerable/sum'` and you're all set. If you are interested in the inner workings see [`enumerable/sum.rb`](https://github.com/marcandre/backports/blob/master/lib/backports/2.4.0/enumerable/sum.rb) – there's simply a `unless method_defined? :sum` after the method's `end`; isn't that beautiful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would simple use `method_defined?`.

Like in this example:

```
# sum implementation for Ruby below 2.4
unless Enumerable.method_defined? :sum
  module Enumerable
    def sum(init = 0)
      inject(init, :+)
    end
end
```